# Can I ensure all tests contain an assertion in test/unit?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit, minitest

With test/unit, and minitest, is it possible to fail any test that doesn't contain an assertion, or would monkey-patching be required (for example, checking if the assertion count increased after each test was executed)?

**Background**: I shouldn't write [unit tests without assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137399/unit-testing-without-assertions) - at a minimum, I should use `assert_nothing_raised` if I'm smoke testing to indicate that I'm smoke testing.

Usually I write tests that fail first, but I'm writing some regression tests. Alternatively, I could supply an incorrect expected value to see if the test is comparing the expected and actual value.

Comment: http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/03/05/the-ego-test/

Answer (score 1):

To ensure unit tests actually verify anything a technique called [Mutation testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing) is used.

For Ruby, you can take a look at [Mutant](https://github.com/mbj/mutant).

Comment: Mutant development moved here: https://github.com/mbj/mutant. (Link is dead). -- Disclaimer, author is commenting.

Answer (score 0):

As PK's link points out too, the presence of assertions in itself doesn't mean the unit test is meaningful and correct. I believe there is no automatic replacement for careful thinking and awareness.

Ensuring the tests fail first is a good practice, which should be made into a habit.

Apart from the things you mention, I often set wrong values in asserts in new tests, to check that the test really runs and fails. (Then I fix it of course :-) This is less obtrusive than editing the production code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think that forcing the test to fail without an assert is really helpful. Having an assert in a test is not a goal in itself - *the goal is to write useful tests*.

The missing assert is just an indication that the test *may* not be useful. The interesting question is: *Will the test fail if something breaks?*. If it doesn't, it's obviously useless.

If all you're testing for is that the code doesn't crash, then `assert_nothing_raised` around it is just a kind of comment. But testing for "no explosions" probably indicates a weak test in itself. In most cases, it doesn't give you any useful information about your code (because "no crash != correct"), so why did you write the test in the first place? Plus I rather prefer a method that explodes properly to one that just returns a wrong result.

I found the best regression test come from the field: Bang your app (or have your tester do it), and for each problem you find write a test that fails. Fix it, and have the test pass.

Otherwise I'd test the behavior, not the absence of crashes. In the case that I have "empty" tests (meaning that I didn't write the test code yet), I usually put a #flunk inside to remind me.