# Is there a name for a test that runs code but asserts nothing?

Tags: testing

I have a few tests that due to not testing anything critical, they run some lines of code but don't properly test the code has any consequence. I'm not trying to argue whether this is a good idea or not, but is there some name for this type of tests?

I currently call them poke tests, they poke they code, but that's as much as they do. I'll know if the poking causes an explosion, but that's all I know.

Answer (score 4):

Martin Fowler calls this [AssertionFreeTesting](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AssertionFreeTesting.html).

Also [smoke test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/137588/367285) seems to be an often used name (although if I understand it correct it is not "mandatory" that it includes no assertions).